# Conditional Insert row and automatic replenishment by using SAS

Tags: sql, sas

> I would like to program a code for auto-inserting the missing row in the table.

My table contain 5 values.

1. YEAR: numeric, range from 2008 to 2010
2. ICD10: character, two types (C40, C41)
3. SEX: character, Two types (1 and 2)
4. AGE_GROUP : numeric, 3 group (4, 9, 14)
5. CASE_NUMBER: numeric

> The data table (table_old) looks like below

|  | YEAR | ICD10 | SEX | AGE_GROUP | CASE_NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2008 | C40 | 1 | 4 | 2 |
| 2 | 2008 | C40 | 1 | 14 | 3 |
| 3 | 2008 | C41 | 2 | 4 | 4 |
| 4 | 2008 | C41 | 2 | 14 | 8 |
| 5 | 2009 | C40 | 1 | 9 | 9 |
| 5 | 2009 | C40 | 2 | 14 | 6 |
| 6 | 2009 | C41 | 1 | 9 | 10 |
| 7 | 2010 | C40 | 1 | 4 | 4 |
| 8 | 2010 | C41 | 1 | 9 | 5 |
| 9 | 2010 | C41 | 1 | 14 | 6 |

> How Could I program a loop or Recursion to get the table (table_new) below

|  | YEAR | ICD10 | SEX | AGE_GROUP | CASE_NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2008 | C40 | 1 | 4 | 2 |
| 2 | 2008 | C40 | 1 | 14 | 3 |
| 3 | 2008 | C40 | 1 | 19 | 0 |
| 4 | 2008 | C40 | 2 | 4 | 0 |
| 5 | 2008 | C40 | 2 | 14 | 0 |
| 6 | 2008 | C40 | 2 | 19 | 0 |
| 7 | 2008 | C41 | 1 | 4 | 0 |
| 8 | 2008 | C41 | 1 | 14 | 0 |
| 9 | 2008 | C41 | 1 | 19 | 0 |
| 10 | 2008 | C41 | 2 | 4 | 4 |
| 11 | 2008 | C41 | 2 | 9 | 0 |
| 12 | 2008 | C41 | 2 | 14 | 8 |
| 13 | 2009 | C40 | 1 | 4 | 0 |
| 14 | 2009 | C40 | 1 | 9 | 9 |
| 15 | 2009 | C40 | 1 | 14 | 0 |
| 16 | 2009 | C40 | 2 | 4 | 0 |
| 17 | 2009 | C40 | 2 | 9 | 0 |
| 18 | 2009 | C40 | 2 | 14 | 6 |
| 19 | 2009 | C41 | 1 | 4 | 0 |
| 20 | 2009 | C41 | 1 | 9 | 10 |
| 21 | 2009 | C41 | 1 | 14 | 0 |
| 22 | 2009 | C41 | 2 | 4 | 0 |
| 23 | 2009 | C41 | 2 | 9 | 0 |
| 24 | 2009 | C41 | 2 | 14 | 0 |
| 25 | 2010 | C40 | 1 | 4 | 4 |
| 26 | 2010 | C40 | 1 | 9 | 0 |
| 27 | 2010 | C40 | 1 | 14 | 0 |
| 28 | 2010 | C40 | 2 | 4 | 0 |
| 29 | 2010 | C40 | 2 | 9 | 0 |
| 30 | 2010 | C40 | 2 | 14 | 0 |
| 31 | 2010 | C41 | 1 | 4 | 0 |
| 32 | 2010 | C41 | 1 | 9 | 5 |
| 33 | 2010 | C41 | 1 | 19 | 6 |
| 34 | 2010 | C41 | 2 | 4 | 0 |
| 35 | 2010 | C41 | 2 | 9 | 0 |
| 36 | 2010 | C41 | 2 | 19 | 0 |

> In simple, I want to insert the missing row and fill 0 to CASE_NUMBER.

> I am a new for SAS, thx.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in SQL using `cross join` and `left join`.  The idea is to generate all the rows and then bring in the existing data:

```
proc sql;
    select y.year, i.icd10, s.sex, a.age_group,
           coalesce(t.case_number, 0) as case_number
    from (select distinct year from mytable) y cross join
         (select distinct icd10 from mytable) i cross join
         (select distinct sex from mytable) s cross join
         (select distinct age_group from mytable) a left join
         my_table t
         on t.year = y.year and t.icd10 = i.icd10 and
            t.sex = s.sex and t.age_group = a.age_group;
```

Comment: Could you explain more detailly?

Comment: Then, it show that ERROR: File WORK.MYTABLE.DATA does not exist.

Comment: @TsengChihYu . . . This is your data.  You need to reference your data set correctly.

Comment: ```select YEAR, newICD10, SEX, AGE_GROUP,
           coalesce(CASE_NUMBER, 0) as CASE_NUMBER
    from (select distinct YEAR from HOD.export_BS) YEAR cross join
         (select distinct newICD10 from HOD.export_BS) newICD10 cross join
         (select distinct SEX from HOD.export_BS) SEX cross join
         (select distinct AGE_GROUP from HOD.export_BS) AGE_GROUP left join
         HOD.ex
         on HOD.ex.YEAR = HOD.export_BS.YEAR and HOD.ex.newICD10 = HOD.export_BS.newICD10 and
            HOD.ex.SEX = HOD.export_BS.SEX and HOD.ex.AGE_GROUP = HOD.export_BS.AGE_GROUP;```

Comment: Do you mean this?

Comment: I couldn't understand the naming of y.year, i.icd10, s.sex, a.age_group and my_table t in your code.

Comment: Does it mean that y.year, i.icd10, s.sex, a.age_group are the column names of my initial table?

Comment: Does it mean that my_table t is the result table?

Comment: @TsengChihYu . . . `mytable` is whatever your dataset is called.

Comment: proc sql;
 select tableold.YEAR, tableold.newICD10, tableold.SEX, tableold.AGE_GROUP,
 coalesce(tablenew.CASE_NUMBER, 0) as CASE_NUMBER
 from (select distinct YEAR from tablenew) YEAR cross join
         (select distinct newICD10 from tablenew) newICD10 cross join
         (select distinct SEX from tablenew) SEX cross join
         (select distinct AGE_GROUP from tablenew) AGE_GROUP left join
   tablenew t
         on tablenew.YEAR = tableold.YEAR and tablenew.newICD10 = tableold.newICD10 and
            tablenew.SEX = tableold.SEX and tablenew.AGE_GROUP = tableold.AGE_GROUP;

Comment: Does you mean this?

Comment: SAS always show that ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: !, !!, &, ), *, **, +, ',', -, /, <, <=, <>, =, >, >=, ?, AND, BETWEEN, 
               CONTAINS, EQ, EQT, GE, GET, GT, GTT, IN, IS, LE, LET, LIKE, LT, LTT, NE, NET, NOT, NOTIN, OR, ^, ^=, |, ||, ~, ~=.  
 
 ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.

Comment: ```proc sql;
 select tableold.YEAR, tableold.newICD10, tableold.SEX, tableold.AGE_GROUP,
 coalesce(tablenew.CASE_NUMBER, 0) as CASE_NUMBER
 from (select distinct YEAR from tablenew) YEAR cross join
         (select distinct newICD10 from tablenew) newICD10 cross join
         (select distinct SEX from tablenew) SEX cross join
         (select distinct AGE_GROUP from tablenew) AGE_GROUP left join
   tablenew t
         on tablenew.YEAR = tableold.YEAR and tablenew.newICD10 = tableold.newICD10 and
            tablenew.SEX = tableold.SEX and tablenew.AGE_GROUP = tableold.AGE_GROUP;```

Comment: @TsengChihYu . . . The code in your comment **is not** the code in the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I still don't understand what you code meaning, I only have the one table, table_old and the conditional rule in initial. As I know that there are must two table in the first for using cross join and left join functions in SAS.

Comment: Because MYTABLE in my code have a libname, HOD, MYTABLE name look like HOD.new.  I couldn't understand the naming of  y.year, i.icd10, s.sex and a.age_group. Does it mean that They are the column header name?

Comment: Is it a correct naming for the code? Just like HOD.new.year? HOD is the libname. new is the table name. year is the column header. Thank you very much for your patience in explaining the things to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try the SPARSE option in PROC FREQ for your particular use case. If the value is in the table somewhere it will fill it in. If the value is never in the table anywhere for any category then this will not work. In that case you need to use a different approach, usually the PRELOADFMT trick.

```
 proc freq data=have;
   table year*icd10*sex*age_group / sparse out=want;
   weight case_number;
 run;
```

Comment: Could you explain more detailly?